# Show airplay/route button on default video player in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

Why is it so difficult to show the airplay button in the default video player? Why isn't there a simple on/off switch? My app has a webview in place and videos that open through the webview open the default video player with no airplay button.

I tried using MPVolumeView and got the button to display in a view, but I cannot figure out how to show it in the place it normally should show, see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xdoo.jpg

Comment: Have you tried setting the 1mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay1 property of your webview to YES? It should be YES by default. Also, are you sure that the content you are trying to play does not block AirPlay? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay

Comment: Yes I have mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay set to Yes, and I tried different contents and none of them show the airplay button.